# ngClass works only once based on a condition, how to apply a class using a continuous changing value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular7

I am trying to apply a conditional class based on child value which is continuously changing. This class is working fine based on default value but if value is changed I wanna change class also.`<div [ngClass]="{'myClass': applyClass== true" >`

Comment: you can use `&&` to have multiple assignments

Comment: [ngClass]="{'classOn': applyClass === true, 'classOff': applyClass === false}" This will act to handle both eventualities, ie your changing value. For more complex issues, I suggest putting the login in a method in the component file.

Comment: What do you mean by `based on child value` ?

Comment: my child is a form So, I am getting value from that form.

Comment: There are not multiple conditions but only one condition is changing continuously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same as like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'myClass': applyClass == true, 'changedClass': applyClass == false" >
```

Or as like this:

```
<div [class.myClass]="applyClass == true" [class.changedClass]="applyClass == false" >
```

Comment: Nope. `ngClass` will work as much as you want. Read https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: Is there any way to use *ngIf to apply class?

Comment: You can not use *ngIf directly. And you dont need to do that. Because, ngClass works with condition as like *ngIf

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically assign the class using property binding.

```
<div [class.foo]="isActive"></div>
```

Where foo is the css class, and isActive is a variable that you change.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `[ngClass]`. Something like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'classToBeApplied': applyClass}">
  This is a div
</div>

<button (click)="toggleApplyClass()">
  Toggle Apply Class
</button>
```

ComponentClass:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  applyClass = false;

  toggleApplyClass () {
    this.applyClass = !this.applyClass;
  }

}
```

Component CSS:

```
.classToBeApplied {
  background: red;
}
```

Here's a **[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrsbrg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)** for your ref.